# Function is not defined in setInterval in a nodeJS Class and in switch/case

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I wanted to create a class, where I create an interval using the `setInterval()` function, if a certain variable has a certain value. As a handler, I put in a predifined function, however, when trying to run the code, it says that the function is not defined. Here is the code.

```js
class Bot {
    i = 0;
    constructor() {
        switch (this.i) {
            case 0:
                this.interval = setInterval(this.foo, 1000);
                break;
        }
    }

    foo = () => {
        console.log("hi")
    };
    //Other Syntaxes I tried without luck:
    foo = function() {
        console.log("hi");
    }

    function foo() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
    foo() {
        console.log("hi");

    }
    //I also tried first defining the function, and then creating a constructor
}
```

EDIT:
I have decided to share the full code with you, however, I would just like to add that I know that there is already a very powerful library that allows to run a Bot on Discord, but it's about doing it yourself. Here you go:

```js
class Bot {
  ws = new WebSocket('wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json');

  sequence = null;
  heartbeating;
  token;
  constructor(token) {
    this.token = token;
    this.ws.on('open', this.open);
    this.ws.on('message', this.incoming);
    this.ws.on('close', this.close);
  }
  open() {
    console.log("open");
  }
  incoming(payload) {
    var data = JSON.parse(payload);
    switch (data.op) {
      case 10:
        //This is the problematic line where I'm trying to enter the function.
        this.heartbeating = setInterval(this.heartbeat, data.d.heartbeat_interval);
        break;
      case 11:
        console.log("Heartbeat ACK");
        break;
      default:
        console.log(data);
    }
  }
  close(e){
    console.log(e);
  }

  heartbeat() {
    var payload = {
      op: 1,
      d: sequence
    }
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
  }
  identify(){
    //TODO identify with Discord
  }
}
```

Additionally, I want to apologize for not having shared the actual Error Message with you: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined`

Comment: How did you try to run it?  Also as a side note; your constructor is overly complicated.  `i` always starts out as `0` from your snippet.

Comment: @Taplar I tried running it from my command line, by putting this code into a file and then using `node filename.js`. This is just a recreation of the code that the problem originated on, which I mainly created to see if I could reproduce my issue, and now that I have the remake, I might as well use this reproduction as it does not contain irrelevant code.

Comment: I edited my answer regarding your "question edit". Take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
class Bot {
    i = 0;
    constructor() {
        switch (this.i) {
            case 0:
                this.interval = setInterval(this.foo, 1000);
                break;
        }
    }

    foo = function() {
        console.log("hi");
    }

}
const b = new Bot();
```

This works for me. But it will start the interval right after creating the Object instance `new Bot();`
If you what to have control over the interval you can do something like this:

```
class Bot {
    i = 0;
    constructor() {
        switch (this.i) {
            case 0:
                this.startInterval = () => { this.interval = setInterval(this.foo, 1000); }
                break;
        }
    }

    foo = function() {
        console.log("hi");
    }

}
const b = new Bot(); // Creating new Object instance
b.startInterval(); // start intverval
setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(b.interval)}, 4000); // end interval after 4000 milsec
```

**Edit**:
The payload of the ws response is an object so will need to parse the payload.data instead of the payload, like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(payload.data);
```

I don't know anything about the ws api of gateway.discord.gg so you should use more `console.log` to be sure with what are you working with.

Comment: The Discord Gateway sends an opcode alongside with its requests, to describe the content of the payload, and that's what I'm checking for, and since it can check for the opcodes, I assume that my payload processing works just fine. I also managed to use `console.log` in an effort to isolate the heartbeat rate. Therefore, I assume that this is not the error. By the way, here is an example payload from `console.log`: `{"t":null,"s":null,"op":10,"d":{"heartbeat_interval":41250,"_trace":["[\"gateway-prd-main-hzgl\",{\"micros\":0.0}]"]}}`

Answer (score 0):

You `constructor` is overly complicated and really evaluates to the same thing I coded in the `constructor` below - this is because `i` will is always initialized  to `0` at the point when the `constructor` is called. As far as the syntax, just using a regular class method should do the trick.

```js
class Bot {
  i = 0;

  interval; //I like to explicitly declare the class members (tho not necessary)

  constructor() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.foo, 1000);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('foo called..');
  }
}

const b = new Bot();
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in a previous comment, this is a recreation of my issue, in which I removed obsolete code to see if I can recreate the issue, and to simplify getting the error. That is also why I checked if the value of `i` was 0 or not, because in the original code, the value in question is not always 0, so I did the switch/case thing.

Comment: The value of `this.i` in the constructor in the question will always be `0`. The constructor is only called once to create a new instance of the class. Or are you saying that you sometimes initialize `i` to some other value? - just trying to understand so I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I remade the issue, where I couldn't put a function as a parameter in a setInterval, if the setInterval is placed inside of switch/case. In my actual code as seen in my recent edit, the value that is checked for is not always the same, so I'd really like to keep the switch/case.

Answer (score 0):

The event handler was called from the `WebSocket` Object, therefore, the `this` keyword returned the `WebSocket` object, not the `Bot` class. A workaround I haven't tested yet could be to try to pass the Bot object as a parameter in the event listener, and should I succeed at this, I will edit this reply.